# Can I test Android smartphones applications on Samsung Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android

Can I test Android smartphones applications on Samsung Galaxy Tab ?

Let's say I want to develop Android applications for HTC,and I only have Galaxy.

Can I simulate smaller resolutions on Galaxy to see how it would work on HTC ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a predefined AVD from Samsung.
This allows to integrate the Samsung Galaxy Tab into the AVD manager and Eclipse.

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

Answer (score 1):

Just create some android emulators with different screen sizes. Also testing on emulator will be faster and easier to debug.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Comment: ok thanks, but still you know.. it would be nice to properly interact with your application, rather than mouse

Comment: @Patrick Most part of testing still will be more handy in emulator.

Comment: Ok, cool and is also possible to test it with touch interaction style ?

Comment: @Patrick Mostly yes. The biggest problem would be multi-touch.